# How to make the player to look at multiple targets depending on the closest target using Inverse Kinematics (IK)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In lookObjects I have two cubes and each cube is rotating around the player in a different speed, but the player is looking only the second cube in the list lookObjects and never looking at the first cube.

I want that the player will know to switch between the lookObjects depending on the one that is closest because now even if the second cube is behind the player and he is not looking at it it's not switching to the first cube that is in front of the player at the moment.

The logic should be that if one of the cube is out of the player sight switch to the other one if the other one is in the player sight.

- why it's not switching between lookObjects?
- what to do if both cubes(lookObjects) are in front of the player how to decide on which one to look at ? what should be the logic in that case?

The code is attached to the player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKTests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform finger;

    public List<Transform> lookObjects = new List<Transform>();
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;

    private Animator animator;
    private Transform lastPrimaryTarget;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (finger != null && lookObjects != null && lookObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawLine(finger.position, lookObjects[0].position);
        }
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObjects != null)
        {
            Transform primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            foreach (Transform target in lookObjects)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;
                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = dotProduct;
                closestLookWeight = float.MinValue;
                if (lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    primaryTarget = target;
                }

                animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 1);
                animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 1);
                animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, target.position);
                animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, target.rotation);
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);//finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.position);
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);//finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.position);
                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to look at something behind the character then you need to decide how far the neck can turn and you may want to consider turning the body as well as the head (Assuming the character is humanoid). Ultimately, we can't tell you what logic to use without completing the project on our own. Just try to use common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop
Use `Vector3.Distance(Transform A, Transform B)` on every Transform to get the look order
then you can use `transform.LookAt(Transform target)` to look at the object